# Does an exact sequence of commutative group schemes define an exact sequence of sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, exact-sequence, etale-cohomology, group-schemes

Suppose we are given an exact sequence
$$ 0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$$
of commutative group scheme over a field $k$. Then does the sequence define an exact sequence of étale sheaves on a $k$-scheme $X$? 
I think the question is elementary, but I get confused.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the question from?

Comment: This is not going to be true in general unless you assume that $A$ is smooth over $k$, in which case it is true (e.g. this is automeatic if $k$ is of characteristic $0$).